# Update custom control Width and Height property using AdaptiveTriggers

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, visualstatemanager, windows-community-toolkit

I try to find how I can update the Width and Height properties of my custom control.

I have used the RadialProgressBar implementation found in UWP Community Toolkit pull request [#828](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/pull/828) for 1.5 milestone.
I can set the Width and Height on the custom control and it will work but I need to set different Width and Height values depending on the display resolution.

- [RadialProgressBar.xaml](https://gist.github.com/igorissen/4fceeefd7a82604357a5148439b1c3a3#file-radialprogressbar-xaml)
- [RadialProgressBar.cs](https://gist.github.com/igorissen/4fceeefd7a82604357a5148439b1c3a3#file-radialprogressbar-cs)
- [Page.xaml](https://gist.github.com/igorissen/4fceeefd7a82604357a5148439b1c3a3#file-page-xaml)

I'm doing something wrong I think but I can't find what.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the answer to this question [UWP XAML Change Style of a target with VisualStateManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668527/uwp-xaml-change-style-of-a-target-with-visualstatemanager).

I need to put the VisualStateManager in the Template of the control.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:RadialProgressBar">
            <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                <!-- Put the VisualStateManager definition here -->
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I have updated [RadialProgressBar.xaml](https://gist.github.com/igorissen/4fceeefd7a82604357a5148439b1c3a3#file-radialprogressbar-xaml) file in my gist.